# ibatis and delimiter in mysql functions

Tags: mysql, ibatis, mybatis, delimiter

I tried to use the following example from [Big DBA Head](http://www.bigdbahead.com/?p=185) in a ibatis migration script.

```
delimiter //
drop function if exists true_function //
create function true_function(p_param int) returns int
  deterministic
  sql security invoker
  return true
//

drop function if exists get_next_value//
create function get_next_value(p_name varchar(30)) returns int
  deterministic
  sql security invoker
begin  
  declare current_val integer;

  update mysql.sequences 
    set value = value + 1
    where name = p_name 
      and true_function((@current_val := mysql.sequences.value) is not null);

  return @current_val;
end//
delimiter ;
```

But the ibatis throws this error:

> ...Error executing: delimiter //
>   drop function if exists get_next_value_test //
>   create function get_next_value_test(p_name varchar(30)) returns int 
>     deterministic 
>     sql security invoker 
>   begin
>     declare current_val integer
>   .  Cause: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'delimiter //...

I already tried to set allowMultiQueries and send_full_script but without success.
Do you have any idea to get this script executed?

Thx,
T.

Comment: The error is related to get_next_value_test function but I dont think the code you posted has this function

Answer (score 4):

I hit the same problem...

The following site seems to provide an answer to this problem.

https://github.com/mybatis/migrations/issues/49

Granted, it is using MyBatis instead of iBatis, but that might be a good move considering that iBatis is 'retired'.

The basic answer to to replace

```
delimiter //
```

with

```
-- @DELIMITER //
```

and then to replace

```
delimiter ;
```

with

```
-- @DELIMITER ;
```